# how to find nth term in a fibonacci series or sum of a series of fibonacci numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

**A series is given as $1,6,7,13,20,33,.......$ and so on Find the sum of first 52 terms?**

what i know is

The sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers is the **[(n + 2)nd Fibonacci number - 1]** .
So the sum of first 52 fibonacci numbers is **[54th fibonacci number - 1]**

now i have no clue about how to find nth no of a Fibonacci series . is there any method to evaluate nth term in Fibonacci series? here how can i find 54th term of the series?

note :: its a aptitude exam's question and on an average 1-2 mins allowed per question.so is there any faster method of finding nth term in a fibonacci series. i want to avoid the manual search procedure because its too time taking procedure

Comment: Look up solving recurrence relations.  You have to solve the recurrence relation: $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with initial conditions $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$.

Comment: There is a free book online about this stuff by Herbert Wilf. Google for it.

Answer (score 6):

If $a_{n+1} = a_n+a_{n-1}$,
$a_n = a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}$.
Therefore

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k
&=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\\
&=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{k+1}-a_{k-1})\\
&=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k+1}- \sum_{k=1}^na_{k-1}\\
&=a_0+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} a_{k}- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k}\\
&=a_0+(\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} a_{k}+a_n+a_{n+1})- (a_0+a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}a_{k})\\
&=a_0+(a_n+a_{n+1})- (a_0+a_1)\\
&=a_{n+2}- a_1\\
\end{align}
$

This is your statement about the sum,
but it is true for *any* sequence
that satisfies the Fibonacci 
recurrence, not just
the standard one.

So,
you only ("only"!)
have to compute $a_{n+2}$.

As shown in the standard way
by Adi Dani,
the generating function for
the $a_n$ is
$F(x)=\dfrac{1+5x}{1-x-x^2}$.

You then have to write
$1-x-x^2
=(1-ax)(1-bx)$
in the usual standard way
(all this is the traditional way
to get Binet's formula),
get $a$ and $b$,
find $c$ and $d$ such that
$\dfrac1{(1-ax)(1-bx)}
=\dfrac{c}{1-ax}+\dfrac{d}{1-bx}
$,
write
$F(x)
=\dfrac{1+5x}{1-x-x^2}
=(1+5x)\big(\dfrac{c}{1-ax}+\dfrac{d}{1-bx}\big)
$,
and get the power series for
$F(x)$
using
$\dfrac{1}{1-rx}
=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} r^j x^j
$.

Have at it.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, well the 54th term of the series can be found as follows: compute $\pmatrix{1&1\\\ 1&0}^{53}$ then multiply by the transpose of (6,1) , the vector will be to the right of the matrix. There are fast multiplication schemes for computing the matrix.

$\pmatrix{1&1\\\ 1&0}^{32}$ * $\pmatrix{1&1\\\ 1&0}^{16}$ * $\pmatrix{1&1\\\ 1&0}^{4}$ * $\pmatrix{1&1\\\ 1&0}$ * (6,1)^T

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence is $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},n\geq2,a_0=1,a_1=6$$

Use generating function $$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=1+6x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n=1+6x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n=$$
$$=1+6x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^n+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^n=$$
$$=1+6x+x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}$$
we see that$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}=F(x)-1$$ and
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}=F(x)$$
from above
$$F(x)=1+6x+x(F(x)-1)+x^2F(x)$$
$$F(x)=1+5x+xF(x)+x^2F(x)$$
$$F(x)=\frac{1+5x}{1-x-x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

I know that this doesn't completely answer your question, but it gives you what you want for the first half of the question title. For large $n$, it sounds like a closed form expression is more appropriate than computing larges sums:

The $n$-th Fibonacci number $F_n$, using the floor function, is given by:

$$ F_n = \Bigg\lfloor \frac{{\phi}^n}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1}{2} \Bigg \rfloor, \quad n \geq 0$$

Alternatively, you could use the nearest integer function:

$$ F_n = \left[ \frac{{\phi}^n}{\sqrt{5}} \right],  \quad n \geq 0$$

where $\phi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.6180339887\cdots$ which is the Golden Ratio.

Comment: Now I'm curious, is it 570921718804 ?

Comment: I find that $F_{54} = 86267571272$

Comment: matrixpower[{{1,1},{1,0}},53] = {{139583862445, 86267571272}, {86267571272, 53316291173}} now multiply a11 by 6 and add it to a12, that should be the 54th term of the series.

Comment: 570921718804 is the 53rd term of the sequence minus 1.